# Postgis nearest coordinates

Tags: postgresql, location, postgis

I'm trying to make a REST service that returns a list of places ordered by distance from the user coordinate. I found this query using postgis:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table 
ORDER BY your_table.geom <-> "your location..."
LIMIT 5;
```

But I'm not able to apply this to my actual database. I have a table that contains these columns:

```
title, address, description, latitude, longitude
```

all these values as Strings.

I'll be very happy if someone help me. Thx!

Comment: dont you have geom field on your table?

Comment: [`<->`](http://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html) *For PostgreSQL below 9.5 only gives centroid distance of bounding boxes and for PostgreSQL 9.5+, does true KNN distance search giving true distance between geometries, and distance sphere for geographies.*

Answer (score 2):

I dont know why, but `ORDER BY <->` isnt exact. Sometime the closest link is on the 3rd position. So I get 101 element and then use distance to selected the closest one.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION map.get_near_link(
    x numeric,
    y numeric)
  RETURNS TABLE(Link_ID int, distance int) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    strPoint text;      
  BEGIN
    strPoint = 'POINT('|| X || ' ' || Y || ')';

    With CTE AS (
        SELECT Link_ID, 
               TRUNC(ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText(strPoint,4326), geom  )*100000)::integer as distance             
        FROM map.vzla_seg S
        ORDER BY 
                geom <-> ST_GeomFromText(strPoint, 4326)
        LIMIT 101
   )
   SELECT *
   FROM CTE
   ORDER BY distance
   LIMIT 5
```

Comment: +1; this is really close to the ["hybrid query" example in the docs](http://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html) about handling the `<->` operator before 9.5.

Comment: Thanks @pozs. Now I know why the `order <->` isnt exact. Is because `For PostgreSQL below 9.5 only gives centroid distance of bounding boxes and for PostgreSQL 9.5+, does true KNN distance search giving true distance between geometries, and distance sphere for geographies.` I had 9.4 until very recently.

Comment: @pozs Interesting they dont use the `ST_GeomFromText` function anymore. just cast the string to geometry. I think Im getting older :(

Comment: yes, exactly. Above 9.5 a simple `ORDER BY ... <-> ...` should be enough. -- The cast maybe easier to use in examples, but I'm sure that input syntax have strict rules. `ST_GeomFromText()` has its place, still.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use PostGIS you have to enable the extension in the database. Ideally, you just run the `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` command and it works. **NOTE** form the install page: DO NOT INSTALL it in the database called postgres. For more information visit the [site](http://postgis.net/install/).

Adding a geometry column (spatial data can be stored in this type of columns) to your table:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn(
   'your_schema', 
   'your_table', 
   'geom',   -- name of the column
   4326,     -- SRID, for GPS coordinates you can use this, for more information https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system
   'POINT',  -- type of geometry eg. POINT, POLYGON etc.
   2         -- number of dimension (2 xy - 3 xyz)
);

UPDATE yourtable t SET t.geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(t.x, t.y), 4326)
-- the x and y is the latitude and longitude
```

Now you can use spatial queries on your table like this:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  your_table 
ORDER BY 
  your_table.geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x, y), 4326)
LIMIT 5;
```

**NOTE:** as others mentioned, below PostgreSQL 9.5 <-> isn't always reliable.

Comment: Yeah the `ST_Distance_Sphere` provides you a good solution (if you don't need very accurate distances). Sorry I forgot to mention in my answer that the `ST_Distance` or the `<->` is not a good way to measure distances if you use the SRID 4326.